# Spring boot application for accessing LinkedIn data

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, linkedin-api

Please reply to this question, I develop one spring boot application which accesses LinkedIn data but when I click on "**connect to linkedIn**" button the URL change from "**http://localhost:8080/connect/linkedin**" to "**http://localhost:8080/connect/linkedin#!**"

**LinkedInController.java**

package com.linkedIn;

```
import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;

import org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.LinkedIn;
import org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.LinkedInProfile;
import org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.impl.LinkedInTemplate;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class LinkedInController {

    private LinkedIn linkedIn;
    private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;

    @Inject
    public LinkedInController(LinkedIn linkedIn, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
        this.linkedIn = linkedIn;
        this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloLinkedIn(Model model) {
        if (connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(LinkedIn.class) == null) {
            return "redirect:/connect/linkedin";
        }
        LinkedInProfile linkedInProfile = linkedIn.profileOperations().getUserProfile();
        model.addAttribute("linkedInProfile", linkedInProfile);
        return "hello";
    }
}
```

**\src\main\resources\templates\connect\linkedinConnect.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"></meta>
        <title>Hello LinkedIn</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h3>Connect to LinkedIn</h3>

        <form action="/connect/linkedin" method="POST">
            <input type="hidden" name="scope" value="user_posts" />
            <div class="formInfo">

                <p>You aren't connected to LinkedIn yet. Click the button to
                    connect this application with your LinkedIn account.</p>
            </div>
            <button type="submit">Connect to LinkedIn</button>      
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Project Directory Structure**

[image: Project Directory Structure]

**Controller**

`package com.linkedIn.controller;`

`import org.springframework.social.connect.ConnectionRepository;`
`import org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.LinkedIn;`
`import org.springframework.social.linkedin.api.ProfileOperations;`
`import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;`
`import org.springframework.ui.Model;`
`import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;`
`import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;`

`@Controller`

`@RequestMapping("/linkedin")`

`public class LinkedInController {`

```
`private LinkedIn linkedIn;`

`private ConnectionRepository connectionRepository;`


public LinkedInController(LinkedIn linkedIn, ConnectionRepository connectionRepository) {
    this.linkedIn = linkedIn;
    this.connectionRepository = connectionRepository;
}

@GetMapping
public String helloLinkedIn(Model model) {
    if (connectionRepository.findPrimaryConnection(LinkedIn.class) == null) {
        return "redirect:/connect/linkedin";
    }
    // ProfileOperations user = linkedIn.profileOperations();
    model.addAttribute("linkedInProfile", linkedIn.profileOperations().getUserProfileFull());
    return "linkedin";
}
```

}

[springboot-linkedin-apply Github Project](https://github.com/developergoutam/springboot-linkedin-apply)

**Pages**